# Strange packages interaction: acronyms, silence, hyperref

Tags: hyperref, acronyms

The following does not compile. It only compiles if `silence` package is commented out. Does anyone know why? And how can I use the 3 packages together?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{silence}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{acronym}
\acro{UE}{User Equipment}
\end{acronym}

\section{\acs{UE}}%<-- doesn't work 

\acs{UE}%<-- works

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `silence` package uses a trick that fails when `hyperref` examines the section title in order to extract the information for the bookmarks.

My suggestion is to avoid `\acs` in section titles; you can do it with `\texorpdfstring`:

```
\section{\texorpdfstring{\acs{UE}}{UE}}
```

A different strategy might be to add

```
\makeatletter
\protected\def\sl@Terminator{\sl@Terminator}
\makeatother
```

so that this doesn't loop in an `\edef`, but I'm inclined to believe that this could fail in other situations.

Comment: Thanks! It didn't occur me to use the `\texorpdfstring` but it is in fact a good solution. I also have some doubts about the second approach.

Comment: I have a similarly strange problem (using the same packages). I had a working version with \textorpdfstring in a section titles. Then, for some reason my AUX file got corrupted. After this happened, LaTeX failed to compile if I use \textorpdfstring in a section titles - without it is fine.

Comment: @Philipp Did you delete the aux file before retrying?

Comment: I had to removing the \textorpdfstring command in section titles and delete all files except the *.tex file to make it work again

Comment: @Philipp In order to use `\texorpdfstring` you must load `hyperref`

Comment: As I said - I am using the same packages This includes silence, acronym and hyperref.

Comment: @Philipp I can compile the example in the question after adding `\texorpdfstring` as indicated. Actually the original example works also without it, because `silence` has been updated to fix some bugs after the question was asked.