# Hyperref + Silence + inline maths, doesn't compile

Tags: hyperref, compiling, incompatibility, silence

#### Issue

Document compilation hangs when `\( ... \)` in section title etc. if *both* hyperref and silence are loaded.

#### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{silence}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Hi \(a + b = c\)}

\end{document}
```

#### Where compilation hangs

Compilation output ends like so

```
...
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty))
(./temp.aux) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that the workaround suggested in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/103486/4427 avoids the loop.

However, the bookmark will contain spurious items, so it's much better to exploit `\texorpdfstring`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{silence}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\protected\def\sl@Terminator{\sl@Terminator}
\makeatother

\title{Title}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Hi \(a + b = c\)}

\section{Hi \texorpdfstring{\(a + b = c\)}{a+b=c}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd keep the workaround just in order to avoid infinite loops, but, as you see, the bookmark is wrong for the first case.

Answer (score 1):

Simply do **not use** package `silence`. This package is latest updated in 2012 and there have been a lot of changes in LaTeX packages!

To find errors in your compiled document it is important you can see all errors and warnings and additional informations to be able to recognize errors you can simply not see in the generated pdf!

Comment: That is _precisely_ why I want to use silence. Some of my macros create expected warnings which I have accounted for. I _want_ to see unexpected warnings and without `silence` it can be like finding a needle in a haystack. My current document produces 677 warnings otherwise.

Comment: Well, then there are some things really wrong and you should check each of the warning if you have to act. Never ignore warnings, often you can not see the resulting problems in the pdf! So it is a bad idea to suppress or ignore warnings ...

Comment: It's just a bunch of stuff like "Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode): (hyperref) removing '\limits'." and from `\sbox0{\scshape x\xdef\testB{\the\font}}` which tests for a small-caps font-variant but produces a warning when there isn't one. If you know of a way to account for those I'd love to hear it.

Comment: @tecosaur If you are getting lots of "removing" message you are quite probably doing something wrong, you shouldn't do such tests in places where hyperref is active.

Comment: Oh, those two things are two separate examples.

Comment: @tecosaur well, if you do not know to get rid of that warnings, please create a new MWE resulting in your warning/issue and post it in a new question ...