# Supress font avalibility warning

Tags: warnings

I sometimes use a font without small caps, but want them. Hence I employ the following trick

```
% have \textsc use \fauxsc if \scshape not avalible
\let\textsc\relax
\DeclareRobustCommand{\textsc}[1]{%
  \sbox0{x\xdef\testA{\the\font}}%
  \sbox0{\scshape x\xdef\testB{\the\font}}%
  \ifx\testA\testB\fauxsc{#1}\else{\scshape #1}\fi
}
```

This words great! It just produces a warning every time it runs :(

I can't use silence because of the [silense+hyperref package incompatability](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/507911/hyperref-silence-inline-maths-doesnt-compile)

#### MWE (fauxsc replaced by textbf)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{plex-serif}

% have \textsc use \fauxsc if \scshape not avalible
\let\textsc\relax
\DeclareRobustCommand{\textsc}[1]{%
  \sbox0{x\xdef\testA{\the\font}}%
  \sbox0{\scshape x\xdef\testB{\the\font}}%
  \ifx\testA\testB\textbf{#1}\else{\scshape #1}\fi
}

\begin{document}

Please \textsc{help} me

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{plex-serif}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\textsc}[1]{%
  \ifcsname \f@encoding/\f@family/\f@series/sc\endcsname
     {\scshape #1}%
  \else
    \textbf{#1}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Please \textsc{help} me

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you explain what the test is doing?

Comment: @RaoulKessels When the `.fd` file is read, LaTeX defines control sequences for font selection; for instance, with the standard setup, the normal font set corresponds to `\OT1/cmr/m/n` and there are also control sequences for font sizes.

Comment: @egreg Ok. So the three macros are expanded and if the small caps have been defined in the current font, because the last item is forced to be /sc, it returns true

Comment: @RaoulKessels Yes, that's it.

Comment: @egreg Thank you very much!

Comment: Marvellous! Thank you very much.